# Using an SQL query

Tags: mysql

Are you able to do the following?

```
  $query = "SELECT username, first_name, last_name, gender, 
                   birthdate, city, state, picture,  user_id 
              FROM mismatch_user
             WHERE user_id = '" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "'";
```

Comment: what's the problem with this?

Comment: No - it will cause the end of the world as we know it - please stop!

Answer (score 3):

I have done something like this on my project. To get it to work correctly try this:

```
$query = "SELECT username, first_name, last_name, gender, birthdate, city, state, picture, user_id FROM mismatch_user 
WHERE (user_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_id)."')
";
```

Before doing this query you need to include this so it recognises $user_id:

```
  foreach (array('user_id') as $varname) {
        $user_id = (isset($_POST[$varname])) ? $_POST[$varname] : '';
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

The real question is what are you trying to do?  In short **YES** it will

If you're trying to run that query with just that then **NO** that alone wont, you first need to connect to a database

```
mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pass');
```

Select a database to run the query against

```
mysql_select_db('database');
```

Then you can run the query using the code below, but you should build your query value using `sprintf()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` for a couple of reasons.

1)  It will prevent unwanted data from making its way into your query by only allowing certain types of data, in this case `%d` refers to a signed int, so only a number will be allowed.

2)  The use of `sprintf()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` will help to prevent SQL injection attacks.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT username, first_name, last_name, gender, birthdate, city, state, picture,  user_id 
                  FROM mismatch_user
                  WHERE user_id = %d", mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']));

$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['first_name'];
    echo $row['last_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will go with this: Why not :-) ?

If you having some problems or exceptions, we will need some context to undestand your code.